# Xcode compiler error: library not found for -lPods from profiling an application

Tags: xcode, swift, ios7, swifty-json, xcode-instruments

My `swift` application runs smoothly without errors until I decide to profile the application to run energy diagnostics then I get this error message placed below. To my understanding and research the error occurs specifically if you used a cocoapod library within your application and you run the `.xcodeproj` file instead of the `xcworkspace` file form xcode, but I didn't do such and still got this error message. In my application I made use of the `swiftyJSON` library which works fine. I would like a little help on how to rectify the problem and possibly understand the reason for the error. I am currently using xcode Version 7.2.1 and swift version 2.1.1

> Ld
>   /Users/umorujoseph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MasterProjectv1-amlpviwvhvmesbcyxdchwrmfmgep/Build/Intermediates/MasterProjectv1.build/Release-iphoneos/MasterProjectv1.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MasterProjectv1
>   normal arm64
>       cd /Users/umorujoseph/iOSProjects/MasterProjectv1
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/umorujoseph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MasterProjectv1-amlpviwvhvmesbcyxdchwrmfmgep/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/umorujoseph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MasterProjectv1-amlpviwvhvmesbcyxdchwrmfmgep/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos
>   -filelist /Users/umorujoseph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MasterProjectv1-amlpviwvhvmesbcyxdchwrmfmgep/Build/Intermediates/MasterProjectv1.build/Release-iphoneos/MasterProjectv1.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MasterProjectv1.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.1 -dead_strip
>   -fembed-bitcode-marker -framework SwiftyJSON -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos
>   -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/umorujoseph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MasterProjectv1-amlpviwvhvmesbcyxdchwrmfmgep/Build/Intermediates/MasterProjectv1.build/Release-iphoneos/MasterProjectv1.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MasterProjectv1.swiftmodule
>   -lPods -framework Pods_MasterProjectv1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/umorujoseph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MasterProjectv1-amlpviwvhvmesbcyxdchwrmfmgep/Build/Intermediates/MasterProjectv1.build/Release-iphoneos/MasterProjectv1.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MasterProjectv1_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/umorujoseph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MasterProjectv1-amlpviwvhvmesbcyxdchwrmfmgep/Build/Intermediates/MasterProjectv1.build/Release-iphoneos/MasterProjectv1.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MasterProjectv1
>
> ld: library not found for -lPods clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

below is a snapshot of the same error message.

[image: snapshot of the error message]

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Im running into the same problem.

I can run the app on my phone but this error happens when I try to archive (I disconnected my phone when trying to archive)

Comment: I was unable to fix the error, i later found out that it had to do with cocopod library not been compatible with Architecture. I however found out another application had crashed on my iPad (instagram), i then restarted it and then tried tried the untethered recording to log both energy and network profile and it worked. Hence, i imported the recording from the iPad to the instrument app.

Comment: i spend like 8 hrs troubleshooting this and I have no idea how or why, but the issue disappeared.  it seems like there are many different causes to the problem.  the only thing I can think of that may have helped was I deleted all the assets in the left xCode menu that were in red indicating that they were pointers to assets that were not in the project.  - I tried some suggestions that I read on stack exchange about deleting different build settings and ended up having to rebuild the entire project a couple of times. NOT FUN!!!